# How to make an async Spring Authentication Provider

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

We have some Spring MVC web services which use Spring's [support for async servlets](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-async). As I understand the concept, this allows for greater scalability as the web container creates fewer threads.

We also use Spring Security to secure our services. Is it possible to make the authentication manager and authentication providers run asynchronously as well?

Our authentication provider needs to access a database or external web service. So there will certainly be some delay in the authentication part of the web request. Without an async authentication manager, it seems that the benefits of async controller methods are reduced.

The [Spring Authentication Provider](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html) authenticate() method is a synchronous method.

To clarify, I'm not talking about getting Spring credentials from within an async MVC controller. I've found plenty of documentation on that.

---

Here is how I have my Spring security application context defined currently.

```
<http auto-config="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" create-session="never" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean name="myAuthenticationProvider" class="com.testing.CustomAuthenticationManager"/>
```

My web controller looks something like the following.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Callable<ResponseEntity> getData(@PathVariable String id) {
    return new Callable<ResponseEntity>() {
        @Override
        public ResponseEntity call() throws Exception
        {
        }
}
```

And of course, I have an implementation of CustomAuthenticationManager.

From my understanding of Spring Security and MVC, this is a crude representation of what Spring is doing.

1. Spring Security receives a request through a filter
2. Spring Security gives this to the Authentication Manager, which uses the provided Authentication Provider (CustomAuthenticationManager)
3. The Authentication Provider authenticates the user and gets his authorities
4. If the user has the correct authorities, Spring calls my web controller (getData).
5. When Spring receives a Callable back, Spring calls AsyncContext.start(Runnable).
6. When the Callable completes, Spring completes the AsyncContext.

What I want to add as well is in step #3.

- The Authentication Provider tells Spring (somehow) that it is async.
- Spring calls AsyncContext.start(Runnable)
- The Authentication Provider takes a while to authenticate, then returns a result
- Spring completes the AsyncContext

Comment: Not sure what this means "The Spring Authentication Provider is a synchronous method."  AuthenticationProvider is an interface and its method synchronicity is dependent on the implementation you are using.  Are you asking about whether the Callable will run with the same authentication as the calling thread?  If so, it seems the upcoming version will http://spring.io/blog/2012/12/17/spring-security-3-2-m1-highlights-servlet-3-api-support/#servlet3-async

Comment: What I meant is that the authenticate() method is synchronous. Yes, I could make it asynchronous internally, but that is not sufficient for servlet 3, right? The key to it is to call [AsyncContext.start(Runnable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html#start%28java.lang.Runnable%29) on the servlet request.

Comment: The authenticate method is not synchronized.  Maybe I'm not understanding your terminology?  AuthenticationProviders typically authenticate a token stored in a threadlocal context, so without custom plumbing to do so, or Spring Security 3.2.0-M1 or higher, the callable will not inherit the authentication.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for your help Taylor. I expanded the question some to try to clarify what I'm hoping to accomplish. Essentially, I want my servlet to go asynchronous twice.

Comment: You want the authentication *itself* to be done in the callable?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Though, I know it won't be in the _same_ Callable since that happens after authentication. The authentication can be a somewhat long process as it needs to go to another service or database.

Comment: So for whatever's in your Callable to run under the authentication, you have to authenticate the user *in that thread*.  Spring Security's authentication stuff is based on the idea that the user has been successfully authenticated in that thread.  The thread then proceeds to do whatever you want (read records, write data, whatever) under the assumption that the authentication was successful.  This necessitates authenticating in-thread.

Comment: But, much like how the link in your first comment talks about how you can get the authentication from a different thread, shouldn't Spring be able to do the same thing with the Authentication Provider?

Comment: To actually validate the authentication in a different thread?  But the main or calling thread can't proceed until it's authenticated, otherwise, how do you know the authentication is valid?

Comment: @Taylor You asked how the calling thread can proceed without authentication, but isn't that what Servlet 3 provides - the ability to make a request async and take it off of a thread? I would expect that Spring could make the request async and when the authentication resolves - success or failure - continue as it would have if it were running synchronously.

Comment: so if the calling thread blocks until authentication resolves, what's the point of doing authentication in a thread?

Comment: @Taylor The Servlet 3 async allows handling of a servlet request to happen without blocking the thread. So the calling thread would not be blocked.

Comment: So you're executing the service method/database/transaction/whatever before the authentication completes.  What if the authentication fails?

Comment: Yes, I need to access users from the database before the authentication completes in order to verify that the user can authenticate. If it fails then that use should not be authenticated. Also, the AsyncContext in Java Servlet has a timeout, so that case can be handled as well.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm not making myself clear.  Here's how I understood what you're looking to do: 1) User attempts some action (let's say it's writing to a file) that requires authorization 2) Spring security notes user is not authenticated, and so you want to fire off an asynchronous authentication request 3a) the authentication process is shoved off to another thread, and the action (writting to a file) proceeds as if the user is authenticated OR 3b) the authentication is shoved off to another thread and the action is suspended until authentication completes.

Comment: Both 3a and 3b are flawed.  3a is flawed because if the authentication fails (e.g. user didn't enter correct credentials) the file has already been written to, so you're hosed.  3b is flawed because your calling thread is waiting around for the authentication to complete, so what's the point of doing the authentication in a separate thread?  It's possible I've misunderstood something though, if so please elaborate.

Comment: Yes 3a is certainly flawed. I am suggesting something like 3b. To access a database for credentials requires 3b. I see no way around that. What I want to do is allow Spring to utilize Servlet 3's async support so that we have 3c) the authentication is shoved off to another thread _which runs asynchronously, the current servlet thread is closed_, and the action is suspended until the authentication completes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42611/discussion-between-taylor-and-david-v)